# How do I get all ways to divide a number in multiple numbers?

Tags: java, math

I want to divide a number `x` into `y` pieces and I want all possible configurations to do this. How can I do this efficiently?
Example x=100, y=3. I could do this:

```
    int x = 100;
    for (int a = 1; a < x; a++) {
        for (int b = a; b < x; b++) {
            for (int c = b; c < x; c++) {
                if (a+b+c == x) {
                    //DO SOMETHING
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think this would work (correct me if I'm wrong) but of course is not very efficient at all because I only want the cases where the if statement is true. And with larger `y` it takes ages. How could I do this efficiently?

Comment: Research the topic of *integer partitions*.  Yes, for large numbers it will take ages.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that. Didn't know what it was called so this should point me in the right direction

Comment: You could skip the last `for` and assign `c = x - a - b;`.

Comment: You can have `int[] terms = new int[y]` and exclude equivalent `terms[i]` by requiring that `term[i+1] >= term[i]`.

Comment: well, this wont work, because it doenst fit your requierment "y pieces".
If you want a true solution, y has to be chosen at runtime not at compiletime.

Comment: as well as @timrau's suggestion, your second loop only needs to go to `b < x - a`. Doesn't make a huge difference but would cut out some cycles.

Comment: FYI, I actually wanted to use this to try and bruteforce this puzzle: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/nine-gangsters-and-a-gold-bar by using x=504 and y=18, because a solution with 19 is known. Furthermore I could say that number is never greater than 504/9. But I am beginning to think that this puzzle is not solvable by bruteforce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your algorithm, I can see that you want `x=a+b+c` with `a<=b<=c`.

Obviously for y = 3, we have `1<=a<=x/3`, then `a<=b<=(x-a)/2`, `c=x-b-a`

For an given y, we get: `1<=a1<=x/y`, `a1<=a2<=(x-a1)/(y-1)`, ... `ai<=a(i+1)<=(x-a1-...-ai)/(y-i)`

But in you want a solution for an arbitrary y, you need a recursive algorithm.

Here is a java implementation:

```
public void split(int number, int pieces) {
    total = 0;
    dosplit(number, pieces, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}

private void dosplit(int number, int pieces, List<Integer> begin) {
    if (pieces == 1) {
        if (begin.isEmpty() || (number >= begin.get(begin.size() - 1))) {
            begin.add(number);
            total += 1;
            //DO SOMETHING WITH BEGIN
            begin.remove(begin.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        int start, end;
        start = (begin.isEmpty()) ? 1 : begin.get(begin.size() - 1);
        end = 1 + (1 + number - start)/pieces;
        for(int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
            begin.add(i);
            dosplit(number - i, pieces - 1, begin);
            begin.remove(begin.size() - 1);
        }
    }
```

`split(10,3)` correctly yields :

```
[1, 1, 8]
[1, 2, 7]
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 2, 6]
[2, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 4]
[3, 3, 4]
```

with as little useless steps as possible.

But `split(504, 18)` would yield an unmanageable number or solutions :-(